# Meaning of Flutter map Function

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, mobile-development, flutter-widget

Please I'm need clarification on what the Map funtion and spread  function does in flutter.

```
...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>).map((answer) {
    return Answer(selectHandler: answerQuestion, answerText: answer);}).toList()
```

In the code  above, I have Question map with keys and values, but the transformation process of the list to widget using map function with spread indicated by three  dots, is what I need clarification on. Please someone help me explain to me. Thanks.

Also is there any other recommendation on transforming list to wiidget without using map function?

Comment: map fn is used to access each values of a list and transform to different form. While you could also use a loop: ``for``, ``forEach``. It's your choice. While ``...`` spread operator is used to unpack a list into another list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the spread operation let you combine a `List` element inside another `List`, it's like you say: "merge the elements of that spread list into the main list".

example :

```
list<int> list1 = [1, 2, 3];
list<int> list2 = [4, 5, 6];
list<int> margeOfElementsOfLists = [...list1, ...list2];

print(margeOfElementsOfLists); // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

in the other hand, the `map` method is not related directly to the `Map` object in dart.
it gives you the ability to get a copy of the original list with executing a kind of function on all elements, taking the previous list :

```
print(margeOfElementsOfLists.map((number) => number *2).toList()); // [2,4,6,8,10,12]
```

so in your case, it's like you're saying, for all elements, create a widget that takes the answer as property and makes from it an `Answer` widget, then merge the elements of that list inside of the main `List`, which can be the children `List` of a `Row` or `Column`

Answer (score 0):

I am beginner in flutter...so far I have noticed that map is easy to use than other looping...

I had a created a demo regarding it

here it is ...if it might help u

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   List<int> numbers = [3, 5, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2];

  List<Widget> int_to_widgetlist() {
    // using map u can code as per following
    //return numbers.map((e) => Text(e.toString())).toList();

    // or u can use for loop or any other loop
    List<Widget> widgetlist = [];
    for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
      widgetlist.add(Text(numbers[x].toString()));
    }
    return widgetlist;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: int_to_widgetlist(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and about spread operator its is like

```
var list = [1, 2, 3];
var list2 = [0, ...list];
```